# VBA Multiply Cells in One Sheet and Paste Them to Another

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to multiply the last 3 cells of a column by the last 3 cells of another column in the "DATA" worksheet and paste them onto another worksheet named "Report".

I have this code which doesn't look correct but maybe you can help? :)

```
Sheets("DATA").Activate
' Use this lRow now since the previous one require you to be in a With loop
Range("A" & lRow - 2 & ":A" & lRow).Copy

With Sheets("Report")
.Activate
' Pastes the last 3 cells of Column A into the Month column
.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
.Range("B8").Formula = "Month"
.Range("C8").Formula = "Production Cost"
' Calculates the Production cost
.Range(.Cells(lRow - 3, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy
.Range("C9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C11")
' Calculates the Inventory cost
.Range("C14").Select
.Range("D8").Formula = "Inventory Cost"
.Range("E8").Formula = "Total Cost"
.Range("B12").Formula = "Total"
End With
```

Comment: Is there any error or code just working with no good results?

Comment: What about it "doesnt work"? You couldnt find any other topics about manipulating data from one sheet to another on stack overflow?

Comment: @Teamothy No error code, everything works but that.

Comment: @braX Not of this specific issue, honestly.

Comment: Try not to think like an end user in terms of "copy/paste" - instead, think like a developer in terms of manipulating the data using the object model.

Comment: @braX This makes me think that vlookup could be of use here.

Comment: It's not clear precisely what you want to do. Multiply to get three results or a single number? Why not a formula?

Comment: @SRJ My bad. My objective is to multiple the last 3 cells of both columns and copy/paste those #s onto another sheet.

Comment: Not sure that's any clearer! What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: @SRJ I'm positive the error happens here:                                  .Range(.Cells(lRow - 3, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy                        .Range("C9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C11") Nothing copied gets placed into the range set.

Comment: Do you get an error message and if so is it on that line? It shouldn't be a guessing game.

Comment: @SRJ No error message whatsoever, which is what's odd.

Comment: You need to step through and do some debugging.

Comment: Will do tomorrow. Reading these comments actually let me fix some other calculations I was having issues with. Will get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub asd()

'Fills the labels of the table
Sheets("report").Range("B8").Value = "Month"
Sheets("report").Range("C8").Value = "Production Cost"
Sheets("report").Range("D8").Value = "Inventory Cost"
Sheets("report").Range("E8").Value = "Total Cost"
Sheets("report").Range("B12").Value = "Total"
'Fills the labels of the table

lastrow = Sheets("data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To 0 Step -1
    Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 2).Value = Sheets("data").Cells(lastrow - i, 1).Value
    Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 3).Value = Sheets("data").Cells(lastrow - i, 2).Value * Sheets("data").Cells(lastrow - i, 4).Value
    Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 4).Value = Sheets("data").Cells(lastrow - i, 3).Value * Sheets("data").Cells(lastrow - i, 5).Value
    Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 5).Value = Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 3).Value + Sheets("report").Cells(lastrow - i - 2, 4).Value
Next i

Sheets("report").Range("C12").Formula = "=SUM(C9:C11)"
Sheets("report").Range("D12").Formula = "=SUM(D9:D11)"
Sheets("report").Range("E12").Formula = "=SUM(E9:E11)"
End Sub
```

Try this one out. It is not a really versatile code so if you have trouble with it let me know, it is most probably because your data and mine are in different locations. I'm sharing my "data" sheet, you can use as a reference.[image]

And here is the result in the "report" sheet:[image]

Comment: Trying this now!

Comment: Does not work on my end. Tried it a few times and nothing gets pasted in the report sheet except the totals which are all 0 since no other numbers got put onto the sheet.

Comment: This worked when I ran it on it's own with your data set. Only issues is it's not expandable.

Comment: Con you share your sheets?

Comment: Of course. Pic 1 is DATA pic 2 is Report: https://imgur.com/a/Gg0MvVe

Comment: I can also post my full spreadsheet code as well. Just didn't post it originally as it's sorta long.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, it's been a busy week, hope I can still help. I cannot access the pictures though, is there any other way for you to share them?